# How to consume ResponseBody wrapped object in FeignClient

Tags: spring-cloud-feign

I have Controller class annotated with @RestController which returns simple POJO.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,
        value = "/user",
        headers = "Accept=application/json,application/xml")
public User getUser() throws ApplicationException {
    return new User(1,"FName","LName","ABC LLC");
}
```

This returns User object wrapped in ResponseBody, when I invoke from postman, it returns

```
{

   success: true,
   message: null,
   data: {
      "fname" : "FNAME",
      "lname" : "LName",
      "company" : "ABC LLC",
      "id" : 1
   }
}
```

If I want to use feign client to consume this rest service, what should be my return type and decoder?

If I use String decoder, I can return string value. But If I want User Java object, I tried with JacksonDecoder, the return value is empty object. Any pointers how to integrate @ResponseBody with Fiegn client.

TIA